# How to run a tkinter file on Docker in Windows?

Tags: docker, tkinter

I am trying to run a GUI created using tkinter on Docker.

This is the docker run command:

```
docker run -u=$(id -u $USER):$(id -g $USER) -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw -v $(pwd)/app:/app --rm tkinter_in_docker
```

I am getting the error:

```
unknown shorthand flag: 'g' in -g
See 'docker run --help'.
```

What is the correct way to run to get the desired results?

Comment: what do you get if you just type `echo $(id -u $USER):$(id -g $USER)` ?

Comment: It was a problem because I was using it in windows , Now that I run in linux environment , it does not give that problem. But another problem exist. _tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "127.0.0.1:0.0" It give this error

Comment: How can I set display properly . I tried various thing but it is not working properly

Comment: You need a linux environment with a GUI (desktop) for that to work.  Do you have a full environment available (e.g. Ubuntu), maybe running as a VM if you are using Windows?

Comment: @zeroid Yeah I was able to do that. I run Ubuntu on WSL and then set up X11 server to enable the display.